# How to receive an app update from Play Store

Tags: android, notifications, google-play, updating

I have an app that i used to host on a private server and send the link to the new version by using GCM.
I now host the app on the Play Store. When i have an updated version, i increment the version code and publish it to production. 
Can anyone tell me why the phones are not receiving a notification of the update?
I have checked the notification checkbox in the app itself and i have checked auto-update from within the play store app settings.

I've had a look around SO and certain individuals seem to think that in order to receive a notification, the app must implement GCM? Others think that the Play Store app regularly checks the version number of the installed app against the new one hosted on the Play Store, then notifies.
Can anyone explain what the users ought to see from an updated app on play store and what i have to do for them to receive a notification.

thanks in advance,

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear unchecked auto update from your Google play for the app.
because if that is checked when your app will be updated you will not be asked for permission. it will automatically install update. 
have patience, some times it take more time to send update to users.

There is no need of gsm into this process. uploading new app is enough.

Answer (score 0):

They should receive a notification, if the following are true:

1. They installed the app through the Play Store. If it was downloaded from your web server, they'll get no updates from the Play Store.
2. They have automatic updates enabled.

Even if the above conditions are true, it may take a day or two for the update notification to be displayed.